# I have a json file. How can I send it to the server?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a json file. How can I send it to the server with flutter?

```
{

    "likes":{
        "job_name":"teh",
        "job_address":"teh"
    }
    ,
    "equals":null
}
```

I get the following error :

> type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>' is not a subtype of type
> 'String' in type cast

this is my code:

```
 Map<dynamic, dynamic> body = {
      "likes": {"job_name": "teh","job_address":"teh"},"equals":null};
    Map header = {
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "accept": "application/json",
    };

    await http.post("myurl", headers: header, body: body).then((response) {
     var responseBody = json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes))["jobs"];
      responseBody.forEach((item) {
        jobs.add(JobModel.fromJson(item));
      });
    }).catchError((err) {
      print('Error Message Here: $err');
    });
```

Comment: Please don't mix `await` and `then`, it makes it harder for you to write and harder for anybody (including yourself) to read. Pick one. My preference would be proper `await`, so you can actually have a meaningful answer to the question: Can you tell us what line produces the error?

Comment: thank's.Error Message Here: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Comment: I have to send the JSON file to the server like the example above and the server passes another JSON file to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

Map<String, dynamic> body = {
  "likes": {
    "job_name": "teh",
    "job_address":"teh",
    },
  "equals":null,
};

Map<String, String headers = {
  "content-type": "application/json",
  "accept": "application/json",
};

try {
  final res = await http.post("myurl", body: body, headers: headers);

  final resJobs = jsonDecode(res.body)["jobs"];

  if(resJobs != null) {
    for(final item in resJobs) {
      jobs.add(JobModel.fromJson(item))
    }
  }
} catch(e) {
  print('Error Message Here: $e');
}
```